# Need to run .slice on React Redux Reducer state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an application which is using React, Redux, and Sagas.  I have a reducer which has a state that is an array of objects.  I want this reducer to handle a certain action by removing the first item of the array.  I understand that state needs to be immutable and therefor I cannot simply call .shift.

Here is what I am trying to do now:

```
const flashcards = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'MAKE_FLASHCARD':
      console.log(action.payload)
        return action.payload;
      case 'UPDATE_FLASHCARD_ARRAY':
        return ({
          ...state.slice(1,state.length)
        })
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };


  export default flashcards;
```

The `...state.slice(1,state.length)` works the first time UPDATE_FLASHCARD_ARRAY is called. However it stops working on future attempts.  I discovered this is because state is not actually removing the first index with my slice method, rather it is setting the values of the first index equal to null.

Here is a stringify of the Redux stat to help illustrate this.

Prior to calling UPDATE_FLASHCARD_ARRAY :

```
[{"id":7,"account_id":1,"native_word":"pig","translation":"gris"},{"id":3,"account_id":1,"native_word":"cow","translation":"ku"},{"id":1,"account_id":1,"native_word":"cheese","translation":"ost"},{"id":2,"account_id":1,"native_word":"milk","translation":"melk"},{"id":8,"account_id":1,"native_word":"spider","translation":"ederkopp"}]
```

After calling UPDATE_FLASHCARD_ARRAY :

```
{"0":{"id":3,"account_id":1,"native_word":"cow","translation":"ku"},"1":{"id":1,"account_id":1,"native_word":"cheese","translation":"ost"},"2":{"id":2,"account_id":1,"native_word":"milk","translation":"melk"},"3":{"id":8,"account_id":1,"native_word":"spider","translation":"ederkopp"}}
```

The slice method is clearing returning a state different than the original.  Could someone point out what I am doing wrong here?  All I want to do is remove the first object from the state array every time UPDATE_FLASHCARD_ARRAY is dispatched.

Comment: As @Dominic said, you just need to mutate your array properly.  You're spreading into an object, when you want an array.  This problem has nothing to do with react, redux, or redux-sagas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.slice already returns a new array you don't need to spread it, you're also spreading it into an object that's why you see `{"0":...`:

```
case 'UPDATE_FLASHCARD_ARRAY':
  return state.slice(1,state.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do `return state.slice(1)` instead `return ({...state.slice(1,state.length)})`? The latter creates an object, which has same keys as `Array`, but not actually as `Array`:

```
Array.isArray([1, 2, 3]) === true
Array.isArray({...[1, 2, 3]}) === false
({...[1, 2, 3]}).slice(1) -> TypeError
```